# FullCalendar - drag between 2 calendars

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to use this example -- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/other-calendar-dragging  -- to create a page that shows 2 FullCalendar calendars and allows the user to drag events from one calendar to the other.   I am able to render both calendars, and pull events for each via ajax from a php page.  However, the events only display on the first calendar.  If I comment out this line:
`events: 'ajax/calendar.php?action=get_monthly_patrol_calendar'`
from calendar1, then the events will display on calendar2 only.  I'd really appreciate help to enable events to display on BOTH calendars.

FYI, here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="kt_calendar"></div>
<div id="kt_calendar2" ></div>
```

JS:

```
var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
var show_now_indicator=true;
var YM = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM');
var YEAR = todayDate.format('YYYY');
var MONTH = todayDate.format('MM');
var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var NEXT_MONTH = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

var cal = document.getElementById('kt_calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(cal, {
    plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'dayGridPlugin', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    events: 'ajax/calendar.php?action=get_monthly_patrol_calendar',
    showNonCurrentDates:false,
    isRTL: KTUtil.isRTL(),
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    //aspectRatio: 3,  // see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio
    nowIndicator: show_now_indicator,
    now: TODAY,
    defaultDate: TODAY,
    initialDate: TODAY,
    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
    eventOrder: 'order_by',
    eventLimit: false, // true to allow "more" link when too many events
    navLinks: true,
    eventResizableFromStart: false, //Whether the user can resize an event from its starting edge.
    eventDurationEditable: false, //Allow events’ durations to be editable through resizing.
    eventResourceEditable: reschedule,//Determines whether the user can drag events between resources.
    droppable:reschedule,//Determines if external draggable elements or events from other calendars can be dropped onto the calendar.
    eventStartEditable: reschedule,//Allow events’ start times to be editable through dragging.
    editable: reschedule, //Determines whether the events on the calendar can be modified.
    eventDrop: function(info) {
      reschedule_event(info);
    },
    eventClick: function(info) {
      do_event_click(info);
    },
    eventRender: function(info) {
        var element = $(info.el);
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
    },
    views: {
        dayGridMonth: { buttonText: 'monthly' },
        dayGridWeek: { buttonText: 'weekly' },
        dayGridDay: { buttonText: 'daily' }
    },

});
calendar.render();

var cal2 = document.getElementById('kt_calendar2');
var calendar2 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(cal2, {
    plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'dayGridPlugin', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    events: 'ajax/calendar.php?action=get_monthly_patrol_calendar',
    showNonCurrentDates:false,
    isRTL: KTUtil.isRTL(),
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    //aspectRatio: 3,  // see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio
    nowIndicator: show_now_indicator,
    now: NEXT_MONTH,
    defaultDate: NEXT_MONTH,
    initialDate: NEXT_MONTH,
    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
    eventOrder: 'order_by',
    eventLimit: false, // true to allow "more" link when too many events
    navLinks: true,
    eventResizableFromStart: false, //Whether the user can resize an event from its starting edge.
    eventDurationEditable: false, //Allow events’ durations to be editable through resizing.
    eventResourceEditable: reschedule,//Determines whether the user can drag events between resources.
    droppable:reschedule,//Determines if external draggable elements or events from other calendars can be dropped onto the calendar.
    eventStartEditable: reschedule,//Allow events’ start times to be editable through dragging.
    editable: reschedule, //Determines whether the events on the calendar can be modified.
    eventDrop: function(info) {
      reschedule_event(info);
    },
    eventClick: function(info) {
      do_event_click(info);
    },
    eventRender: function(info) {
        var element = $(info.el);
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay'
    },
    views: {
        dayGridMonth: { buttonText: 'monthly' },
        dayGridWeek: { buttonText: 'weekly' },
        dayGridDay: { buttonText: 'daily' }
    },

});
calendar2.render();
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's Console or Network tools at the times when you've got both events options enabled?

Comment: Btw it looks like your code would put the same set of events into both calendars, since both mention the same URL for the events feed...is that intentional? Maybe it's just me but I'm struggling to see the purpose of displaying the same stuff twice.

Comment: Thanks, ADYson for your comments.  There are no errors in the Network tab.  In the console, it tells me "Failure parsing JSON", generated by fullcalendar.bundle.js.  (I can post that block of code if needed)

The point of having 2 calendars side-by-side is to allow the user to drag events from one month to the next.  ie:  If I need to schedule an event from Dec 30 to Jan 2.  This was the only solution that I could think of -- show 2 months side-by-side.  I am open to a different/better solution if you have one.  (The URL feed is the same, but the month is different.)

Comment: I haven't received a response here, and am stuck not being able to drag from one month to the next/previous month in fullcalendar.  It can't be that fullcalendar won't allow that... any suggestions?  (please!)

Comment: The error makes it sound like one of your calls didn't return valid JSON. Did you check the raw response in the network tab?

Comment: P.S. You're right there's no built-in way to drag an event to a date which isn't already visible on the calendar. But most ppl solve that by having an "edit event" GUI which pops up when the event is clicked, and enables you to modify properties of the event, including setting start/end dates (usually using a datepicker) - that way if someone wants to move the event a long way, they do it like that, but if they only want to move it within the current date range they can drag it for convenience.

Comment: Figured it out!  The second call was failing bec it was running before the first call completed.  I added a delay before loading the 2nd calendar, and now both months load fine:  setTimeout(function() {  loadCal2();  }, 3000);  Thank you, ADyson for your assistance which pointed me in the right direction to solve this.

Comment: So you mean your server can only handle one request at a time??

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  The second call was failing bec it was running before the first call completed.  I added a delay before loading the 2nd calendar, and now both months load fine:
`setTimeout(function() {  loadCal2();  }, 3000);`